# Dockercompose error while trying to npm start my react app

Tags: reactjs, docker, npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

i want to dockerize my react/ django app so i created those docker files and dockercompose
when i type docker-compose up  my DB and backend works fine but i'm getting an error in react ( ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/myyreactproject/public  ) when i try to run the react's dockerfile without mentionning -p 3000:3000 i got the same error but when i type -p 3000:3000 it works fine
i want to start my frontend without the use of "-p" because i can't use it with docker-compose
any help please ?

**this is my react's dockerfile :**

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR '/app/myyreactproject'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install &&\
    npm install react react-dom &&\
    npm install react-confirm-alert --save &&\
    npm install axios &&\
    npm install jsonwebtoken &&\
    npm install jwt-decode
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm" , "start"]
```

**and this is my dockercompose.yml**

```
  version: '3'

  services:
 db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=yassine123
web:
  build: ./projet
  command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - ./projet:/app/projet
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  depends_on:
    - db
frontend:
  build: ./myyreactproject
  command: ["npm", "start"]
  volumes:
    - ./myyreactproject:/app/myyreactproject
    - node-modules:/app/myyreactproject/node_modules
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"

volumes:
node-modules:
```

**and this the error i get :**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got similar issue and adding

```
tty: true
```

in the .yml file, It solved my issue so try adding tty: true in your .yml file